# Google Forms Using Oauth And Python

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Forms form using Python and OAuth. I have obtained the access token for the relevant scopes. I am able to call few protected resources using the access token.

When I try to create a form, I am receiving some errors. The discovery client does not recognize forms. But it recognizes other APIs such as drive.

```
        import os.path

        from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
        from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
        from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
        from googleapiclient.discovery import build
        from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body']

        creds = Credentials(token="...", client_id="...", client_secret="...")
        service = build('forms', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

```
In [61]: service = build('forms', 'v3', credentials=creds)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownApiNameOrVersion                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-bcb27d6a5c49> in <module>
----> 1 service = build('forms', 'v3', credentials=creds)

~/gbms_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    132                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    133                     logger.warning(message)
--> 134             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    135 
    136         return positional_wrapper

~/gbms_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in build(serviceName, version, http, discoveryServiceUrl, developerKey, model, requestBuilder, credentials, cache_discovery, cache, client_options, adc_cert_path, adc_key_path, num_retries, static_discovery)
    289 
    290         try:
--> 291             content = _retrieve_discovery_doc(
    292                 requested_url,
    293                 discovery_http,

~/gbms_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in _retrieve_discovery_doc(url, http, cache_discovery, serviceName, version, cache, developerKey, num_retries, static_discovery)
    403             return content
    404         else:
--> 405             raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion("name: %s  version: %s" % (serviceName, version))
    406 
    407     actual_url = url

UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: forms  version: v3
```

https://developers.google.com/forms/api/quickstart/python the example here works, but it uses the deprecated library `oauth2client`

Versions of the forms API like v2, v3:

```
service = build('forms', 'v2', credentials=creds)
```

I'd appreciate a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to disable static discovery.

```
service = build('forms', 'v1', credentials=creds, static_discovery=False)
```